# What determines who sits to the umpire's left or right?

Tags: rules, tennis

When players arrive on court, they'll put down their bags and towels on seats to the umpire's left and right. Is there a rule that determines who sits where, or is it simply that the first player walking on picks a seat?

Comment: Interesting question.  ATP rules don't seem to say; the ITF rules specify how to decide which end they play from, but not where they sit.  I'm guessing there *is* a rule, or at least an understanding (probably the higher seed gets to pick?) but not sure.